# castle windsor interceptor on method that is calling by another method

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, aop, interceptor, aspect

---

### Interceptor

```
public class CachingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
       // code comes here.... 
    }

}
```

---

### Business Layer

```
public class Business : IBusiness
{
     public void Add(string a)
        {

             var t= GetAll();             
             // code comes here.... 

        }

     [CacheAttribute]
     public string GetAll()
        {
             // code comes here.... 

        }

}
```

---

### Class

```
public class JustForTest
{

     public JustForTest(IBusiness business)
            {

               //if GetAll is invoked directly caching works fine.
               business.GetAll();

               //if GetAll is invoked over Add method caching doesn't work.
               business.Add();                      

            }

  }
```

add method calls GetAll method. If I invoke GetAll method directly, caching works. If Add method calls GetAll Method, caching doesn't work.

Thank You for helping.

Comment: You should resolve the `Business` instance from the `container` and not `new` it up yourself.

Comment: Than you qujck. Actually I did it. I just want to make the code simple. I used installer for implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Interface proxies are created by wrapping proxy target object so with interfaces this is not possible.

You can intercept calls on the same objects, but only for class proxy (provided the method is virtual).
See answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489127/intercepting-method-called-from-a-method-of-the-same-object).

You could also try to structure your code differently, move logic that needs to be cached to services that can be cached without using it's own functions.

Comment: YEs, It seems not easy but It should be some way. I couldn't find any solution.

Everybody calls the method directly.  :|

Comment: Thank you Jacob. I checked your answer. 

Actually  i'm not  professional in Castle. is it ok just modifying my method as virtual. 

Also I read   Krzysztof's answer but it is not clear.

Comment: You can mark the method as virtual but then your client needs to depend on the concrete type and not the interface. A bit ugly and untestable. I would try to change the architecture.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the line

```
var t= GetAll();
```

is **inside** the class `Business`. It can be more clearly written as

```
var t = this.GetAll();
```

`this` is not an intercepted/wrapped instance.

Try dividing the responsibilities of the `Business` class as suggested [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)

Comment: thank you, I see what you mean. 

I shouldn't call GetAll() inside Add() method. However I don't have any idea.

Comment: I assume `GetAll` is a query that returns some data. If `GetAll` was a separate class (a query) that was injected into `Business` then you would not have the problem you are faced with.

Comment: I will put GetAll Method in seperate class. 

Thank you Jacob and Qujck.

Comment: @MuratCabuk: If you read the adviced articles, you don't even need interception at all. You can do this in a much more clean and elegant way using decorators.